# Creating a Self-Signed SSL Certificate

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, self-signed

I am trying to generate the Self-Signed SSL Certificate on windows local system by following steps: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-certificate-self#generate-ssl-certificate

But after running following command in OpenSSL:

```
x509 -req -sha256 -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt
```

I am getting error:

```
8780:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:707:Expect ing: CERTIFICATE REQUEST
error in x509
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: You are feeding an existing certificate request into the `-req` process, whose purpose is to produce a certificate request. TIme to look at the documentation. The real documentation. Not some arbitrary blog. Off topic.

Answer (score 0):

The command you search for is:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey -sha256 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
```

As already mention in comments you need to tell `openssl` this is new key (`-newkey`)